# jQuery: Search and filter one table with two search bars simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I currently have a large table (~500 rows) that I would like to search with two search bars concurrently. By this I mean that I can enter a query into each and the results will match both of them.
I put a sample of the table and all of the javascript into a [Jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/721s6s18/3/).

I have also tried using [jets.js](http://jets.js.org)

```
var jets = new Jets({
    searchTag  : '#stateSearch', // which searchbox?
    contentTag : '#jetsContent', // where is the data?
    columns    : [2]             // which column to search? (index starts at 0)
});
```

The same problem is reproduced with one search by Jets and one by the Jsfiddle code, as well as both with the Jsfiddle code. Two Jets instances on the same page [is not supported](https://github.com/NeXTs/Jets.js/issues/32).

Answer (score 0):

By merging the two functions and using a boolean to see if the query matches both the state field (in the state column) and the name field (in the name column).

```js
   $('#stateSearch, #allSearch').on('keyup', function(e) {

   var stateFilter = $('#stateSearch').val();
   var nameFilter = $('#allSearch').val();

   var stateReg = new RegExp(stateFilter, 'i')
   var nameReg = new RegExp(nameFilter, 'i')

   $('#jetsContent').find('tr').hide().each(function() {
     var $me = $(this);

     var matchesState = $me.children('td:nth-child(3)').text().match(stateReg);
     var matchesName = $me.children('td:nth-child(2)').text().match(nameReg);

     if (matchesState && matchesName) {
       $me.show()
     }

   })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" id="stateSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="2 Letter Code...">
<input type="search" id="allSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Maria">

    <table>
      <tbody id="jetsContent">
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.alexander.senate.gov/">Alexander, Lamar</a></td>
          <td>TN</td>
          <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
          <td>455 Dirksen</td>
          <td>(202) 224-4944</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.barrasso.senate.gov">Barrasso, John</a></td>
          <td>WY</td>
          <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
          <td>307 Dirksen</td>
          <td>(202) 224-6441</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.bennet.senate.gov">Bennet, Michael F.</a></td>
          <td>CO</td>
          <td class="democrat">Dem.</td>
          <td>261 Russell</td>
          <td>(202) 224-5852</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.blumenthal.senate.gov">Blumenthal, Richard</a></td>
          <td>CT</td>
          <td class="democrat">Dem.</td>
          <td>706 Hart</td>
          <td>(202) 224-2823</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.blunt.senate.gov">Blunt, Roy</a></td>
          <td>MO</td>
          <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
          <td>260 Russell</td>
          <td>(202) 224-5721</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.booker.senate.gov">Booker, Cory A.</a></td>
          <td>NJ</td>
          <td class="democrat">Dem.</td>
          <td>359 Dirksen</td>
          <td>(202) 224-3224</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.boozman.senate.gov/">Boozman, John</a></td>
          <td>AR</td>
          <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
          <td>141 Hart</td>
          <td>(202) 224-4843</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.brown.senate.gov/">Brown, Sherrod</a></td>
          <td>OH</td>
          <td class="democrat">Dem.</td>
          <td>713 Hart</td>
          <td>(202) 224-2315</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.brown.senate.gov/">joe shmoe</a></td>
          <td>OH</td>
          <td class="democrat">Dem.</td>
          <td>713 Hart</td>
          <td>(202) 224-2315</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
          <td>Senator</td>
          <td><a href="http://www.brown.senate.gov/">whoever</a></td>
          <td>OH</td>
          <td class="democrat">Dem.</td>
          <td>713 Hart</td>
          <td>(202) 224-2315</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```